# Generating QR codes in serverless with aws-nodejs template

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I need to write a lambda function and send a number in the api request field to genrate the number of QR codes and store them in a S3 bucket.I am using the serverless framework with the aws-nodejs template.
To describe the task briefly lets say I get a number input in the api request PathParameters and based on these number I have to generate those number of QR's using the qr npm package and then store these generated qr's in the s3 bucket

this is what i have been able to do so far.

```
 module.exports.CreateQR = (event,context) =>{
   const numberOfQR = JSON.parse(event.pathParameters.number) ;


    for(let i=0;i<numberOfQR;i++){

     var d= new Date();

     async function createQr(){
      let unique, cipher, raw, qrbase64;
      unique = randomize('0', 16);
      cipher = key.encrypt(unique);
      raw = { 'version': '1.0', data: cipher, type: 'EC_LOAD'}

      // linkArray.forEach( async (element,index) =>{

        let  qrcode = await  qr.toDataURL(JSON.stringify(raw));
        console.log(qrcode);
        // fs.writeFileSync('./qr.html', `<img src="${qrcode}">`)

      const params = {
        Bucket:BUCKET_NAME,
        Key:`QR/${d}/img${i+1}.jpg`,
         Body: qrcode
     };


      s3.upload(params , function(err,data){
       if(err){
          throw err
        }
       console.log(`File uploaded Successfully .${data.Location}`);
      });

      }

    createQr();

   }   





   };
```

I have been  able to upload a given number of images to the bucket but the issue i am facing is the images are not going in the order.I think the problem is with the asynchronous code. Any idea how to solve this issue

Comment: And where are you struggling with ?

Can you show what you have so far, so we can better help you?

Comment: I have created a lambda function and on triggering it the number of required qr's are being generated and are getting stored in the s3 bucket but not in order(like img10 is getting stored before image 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you're not awaiting the s3 to upload, but instead you have a callback.
you should use the `.promise` of s3 and then await it, so you'll wait the file to be uploaded before move to the next one

I changed the example of code

See docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#promise-property

```js
// see the async keyword before the lambda function
// we need it for use the await keyword and wait for a task to complete before continue
module.exports.CreateQR = async (event,context) =>{
   const numberOfQR = JSON.parse(event.pathParameters.number) ;

   // moved your function out of the loop
   function createQr(){
      // ...
      // here we call .promise and return it so we get a Task back from s3
      return s3.upload(params).promise();
   }

    for(let i=0;i<numberOfQR;i++){
     // ....
     // here we await for the task, so you will get the images being created and uploaded in order
    await createQr();
    }


};
```

hope it guide you towards a solution.

Comment: This is even worse because you are mixing up callbacks and promises. That `s3.upload` callback should *not* be there.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi, I completely forgot about it, I'll update the answer, thx for spot it!

Comment: how should i use the async await such that i push my image to a array and once the for loop completes and the array gets populated  then i upload them using map method on the array.